# When I minimize my application and reopen it, resize the layout

Tags: android

Hello the problem is that when minimizing and reopening when pressing any textview, the layout becomes small, but when using my application for the first time it does not, that is, the keyboard does not normally affect the layout, but if I minimize the app and the I reopen the screen is reduced, I will show you an image.

[First time open my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imyKc.png)

[After minimizing and reopening my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcavT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution for this problem. Put the next code in the "OnCreate" of your app.

CODE:

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);